# Determining the order of operations in elliptic curve cryptography: Point doubling vs point addition for obtaining x and y values of a public key

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, private-key, public-key

I have a question regarding the operations performed on an elliptic curve, specifically related to point doubling and point addition. I am trying to understand whether it is possible to determine the order in which these calculations were performed in order to obtain the x and y values of a public key.

To provide some context, in elliptic curve cryptography, point doubling refers to the operation of taking a point on the curve and finding another point on the curve that lies on the same line. This operation involves doubling the coordinates of the point and performing some additional calculations to obtain the new coordinates.

On the other hand, point addition involves taking two points on the curve and finding a third point that lies on the same line. This operation involves adding the coordinates of the two points and performing additional calculations to obtain the new coordinates.

Now, my question is whether there is a way to determine the chronological order in which these calculations were performed `based solely on the resulting x and y values of a public key`. In other words, can we determine whether `point doubling` or `point addition` was performed last to obtain the given x and y values?

I tried using the below script but it only prints `The operation used to obtain the public key was: Point Addition`

```
def is_point_doubling(x, y, x1, y1):
    return x == x1 and y == -y1

def is_point_addition(x, x1):
    return x != x1

def determine_operation(x, y, x1, y1):
    if is_point_doubling(x, y, x1, y1):
        return "Point Doubling"
    elif is_point_addition(x, x1):
        return "Point Addition"
    else:
        return "Invalid"

# Example usage
x = 3
y = 4
x1 = 3
y1 = -4

operation = determine_operation(x, y, x1, y1)
print(f"The operation used to obtain the public key was: {operation}")
```

Any insights or references to relevant research papers or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is not a programming problem and thus is off-topic here. Both [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) have answered related questions in the past and I think this would be on-topic in either of those. Note that a given point may be reachable by the addition of distinct points *or* doubling, so there isn't necessarily a unique way to arrive there.